# Unexpected System Failure

Tags: graphics, google-chrome, logs

This is a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10. I did not uninstall anything. I did add the following though: 

• google-musicmanager-beta
• MusicBrainz Picard
• Clementine
• ps3mediaserver

Here are my problems:

1. Computer suddenly fails
2. Monitor loses video signal (VGA)
3. Monitor goes blank as if PC is off.
4. I have to restart the computer in order to start using it again.

It's been happening for about two months now and I can't figure out why.
I tried checking the system logs, but nothing stands out. I don't really know what I'm reading though. I think it's Chrome, unlikely though, is there any way I can check Chrome logs? This is becoming really annoying, can anyone lead me in the right direction please?
here is the sys.log file (only showing today's though 17th August 2013)
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5995804/
It happened around 12:57, really hope this helps guys, thanks alot.

Comment: Does it happen at random?

Comment: I hope not, that would make this a bit difficult to solve... To answer your question, It seems so. Was hoping to check some logs or maybe post back here with a system log and maybe you guys could explain the possible entries.

Comment: Well, you might try giving us a link to a pasted `dmesg` or `/var/log/Xorg.log` or something, which may help... though you say you've already checked those logs, if we even know what logs you checked and what their contents are it will *improve the quality of your question* and perhaps add useful info. I meant in my previous comment: does it always happen after, say, exactly 5 minutes or 1 minute or something? or does it vary in the amount of time it takes for this to happen after login?

Comment: sorry, its random in that aspect, not specific time limit. Will post back some log entries back tomorrow... going to do some random stuff and hopefully it happens, when it does i willl definitely post back the last, say, twenty lines of the log. Oh btw, i was checking sys.log log. in the log folder. Alright, till tomorrow then.

Comment: OK - but you can feel free to post the entire log to `paste.ubuntu.com` and let us check it out. Be careful not to harm your system even further!

Comment: AHA! so it happened again, i was using MusicBrains Picard when it just shut down, going to paste the sys.log file on paste.ubuntu.com and maybe something there will help you help me!? thanks alot guys

Comment: added to the link to the question (OP)

Comment: bump any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a strange problem: see lines 1004-1008 in your syslog. They say:

```
NVRM: Your system is not currently configured to drive a VGA console
NVRM: on the primary VGA device. The NVIDIA Linux graphics driver
NVRM: requires the use of a text-mode VGA console. Use of other console
NVRM: drivers including, but not limited to, vesafb, may result in
NVRM: corruption and stability problems, and is not supported.
```

Google reveals this thing you can try:

- Open up your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file as root with `gksu gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Fin the line for your current Linux version that begins with `linux   /boot/vmlinuz-<kernel version>`. To the end of that line, add the options `video=vesa:off vga=normal`. ([Source](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1225337#p1225337))
- Logically, if it's a VGA issue, you could use a DVI or HDMI cable instead of a VGA cable to connect your monitor.
- Turn off UEFI or "Secure boot" in your BIOS.

Comment: [shocked] didnt even know that could be a problem. Thanks so much, going to give it a try when i get home. P.S. how did you know that the problem was in those lines? was there something that stood out or was it just your experience that helps you figure these things out?

Comment: It seemed like it might be a graphics card problem, so... I searched for `nvidia` (the name for the module that handles common graphics cards) in your syslog on a hunch, just to eliminate the possibility of it being a driver issue, and lo and behold there it was!

Comment: couldn't find that line, however, there are two other available drivers for this video card (post-release version and experimental version), going to try the post release and see what happens

Comment: If that doesn't work, do paste your `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file to paste.ubuntu.com and we can help you find the line and edit it properly.

Comment: hey again, ok so i tried using the post-release version, still failed,  then thought i'd switch to the recommended version in case it would refresh or something or the other, still doing the same thing. when i'm home i will definitely post the grub.cfg file. 

Thanks for the help, really.

Comment: My Grub File: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6006916/

Comment: Ok, first, install all possible available updates, because you have a slightly stale kernel version. Once finished, open the file as root with `gksu gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`. Then use the search tool (ctrl + F) to find the line that begins with `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-39-generic root=UUID=4c7a2fe9-d063-48bd-8a9c-8dc1ef63bd24 ro`, etc. Edit it so that it says `linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-39-generic root=UUID=4c7a2fe9-d063-48bd-8a9c-8dc1ef63bd24 ro   quiet splash $vt_handoff video=vesa:off vga=normal`. Save the file and reboot.

Comment: thanks @searchfgold6789, giving it a try, will let you know how it goes. fingers crossed!